# sql query - update based on 1 known field and 1 unknown field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using psql 8.4 (not an option to upgrade but I don't think hat should mater for this question).

My relation:

```
BAY -- ID -- LOADER
124 -- 1B -- 5
124 -- 1C -- null
...    ...   ...
124 -- 1Z -- null
```

Every Bay will have multiple ID's but each ID will share the same Loader.  There are multiple Loaders but there will never be a single bay with more than one Loader.  This would be an easy update statement:

```
update table set loader = '5' where bay = '124';
```

But how do I do that for an entire table with hundreds of Bays?  Further I don't know which Bay maps to which loader (even though it is consistent). I just know I need to update the hundreds of new rows for each bay.

I could do a select of all the distinct bays and their corresponding loaders and then throw that into VIM and create a series of update statements? But I was curious about another more elegant way to do the same thing in sql with one statement or only a couple?  My sql knowledge is obviously not advanced.

Comment: I would do it with a program or a stored procedure. Or if there are only a few hundred entries, I would do a select, put the results in a spreadsheet editor (Excel/Calc), construct the queries there and run them from the SQL editor.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one loader for each bay and at least one of the rows already has that loader you can do this:

```
update table set table.loader = (select b.loader from table b where b.bay = table.bay and b.loader is not null limit 1)
where table.loader is null
```

Comment: sorry, I got confused with oracle, update the answer to use limit

Answer (score 0):

Try this, will get not null loader and put it to null ones:

```
UPDATE T1 SET T1.Loader=T2.Loader FROM Table T1 LEFT JOIN Table T2 ON T1.bay=T2.Bay AND T2.Loader IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

"Every bay should have the same loader".  This suggests that your data structure is wrong.  You should have a table that contains the bays.  This table should contain the loader information.

The table you are looking at would then just reference the `Bays` table and get the loader information from there.

If you do need to do this, you can do it with a join:

```
UPDATE T1
    SET T1.Loader = T2.Loader
    FROM Table T1 JOIN
         (SELECT t2.Bay, MAX(T2.Loader) as Loader
          FROM Table T2
          WHERE T2.Loader IS NOT NULL
          GROUP BY t2.Bay
         ) tl
         ON T1.bay = tl.Bay
    WHERE T1.Loader IS NOT NULL;
```

This picks an arbitrary non-NULL loader for each bay and uses it to assign to the `NULL` `Loader`s in the table.

Comment: I edited my explanation.  The solution cannot be an arbitrary loader.  In Bay 124, for example, the null would have to be populated with 5.

Comment: @lostinthebits . . . "arbitrary non-NULL loader for each bay" would be the one loader populated for the bay, if there is only one.  You don't seem to have constraints or other guarantees that the data is currently populated correctly.